# Does the minus symbol preceding a variable make the first variable negative?

Tags: java

We are asked to use for int variables to make the answer equal 20. We are only supposed to change the placement of the plus's and minuses. They have a minus in front of int a. Does that make int a negative?

I've googled the answer but my Googlefu isn't up to par.

```java
public static int a = 1;
public static int b = 3;
public static int c = 9;
public static int d = 27;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int result = - a + b - c + d;
}
```

Comment: What was the value of `result` when you ran this code?

Comment: `int a = 3; System.out.println(- a);` see for yourself

Comment: Did you even try just playing around with it and trying to see what happens?

Comment: The value was 20. And @Tomerikoo of course I did. There was no explanation other than figure it out. I know to NOT come on here and NOT have tried to figure it out on my own.

Comment: I'm just saying, a simple sequence of: `a=1` -> `System.out.println(a)` -> `System.out.println(-a)` and so on will help you understand what's going on all by yourself. Which is more fulfilling :)

Comment: Think about this: `result = - a;`What do you expect the value of result to be?

Comment: Did you do any research on Java operators, even just a simple web search?

Answer (score 3):

In the expression:

```
- a + b - c + d
```

there are 3 different operators, going left to right:

- [Unary minus operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.15.4)
- [Binary plus operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.2)
- [Binary minus operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.2)
- (Binary plus operator again)

In general, unary operators have higher precedence than binary operators, so this expression is equivalent to:

```
(( (- a) + b) - c) + d
```

So, the unary `-` applies to the `a`. From the linked specification above:

> At run time, the value of the unary minus expression is the arithmetic negation of the promoted value of the operand.

So, it doesn't make `a` negative, it results in an expression whose value is the negation of `a`. This happens to be negative, because `a` has a positive value. However, it doesn't *make* `a` anything, `a` is left unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to actually *make* a negative would be to reassign it:

```
a = -Math.abs(a);
```

For a more elaborate answer please have a look at the java language specification, where you can find detailed information on how operators and expressions are evaluated in java (in your case: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.15.4)